# Don't find Textures images into a SKTextureAtlas

Tags: ios

I'm using spritekit on Xcode 5. I created a folder called images with ".atlas" extension and these images inside: bear1.png, bear2.png and bear3.png 
During the simulation this SKTextureAtlas is founded by “[SKTextureAtlas atlasNamed:@"images”]” but when i try to recovery some image using “[ursoAtlas textureNamed:@"bear1"]" it doesn't find the image. I printed the variable temp and it returns "MissingResource.png" and numImages in the code is 0. i expected that numImages was 3.

```
SKTextureAtlas *ursoAtlas = [SKTextureAtlas atlasNamed:@"images"];

SKTexture *temp = [ursoAtlas textureNamed:@"bear1"];

NSLog(@"%@", temp);
int numImages = ursoAtlas.textureNames.count;
NSLog(@"%d", numImages);
```

Answer (score 0):

Everything look fine.
Did you drag images.atlas into the project?
or you can try to create new test_image.atlas and drag into project.

Comment: I created "test_image.atlas" and dragged into my project but it didn't work. I tried another thing: i found a tutorial on internet and downloaded the sample project but it doesn't work too. it shows  missing resource images ( a "x" inside a square) instead of the expected tutorial images